# Call ssh-copy-id in an Ansible playbook - How to handle password prompt?

Tags: ssh, ansible

I have two servers. I manage `serverA` with Ansible. `serverB` is not managed with Ansible. I want `serverA` to be able to access `serverB` by copying the `ssh_pub_key` of `serverA` to `serverB`.

This can be done manually by calling `ssh-copy-id user@serverB` on `serverA`.

I want to do this with Ansible on `serverA` automatically.

```
- name: Register ssh key at serverB
  command: ssh-copy-id -i /home/{{user}}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@serverB
```

Calling `ssh-copy-id` requires me to enter my ssh password for user@serverB, so the key can be copied.

How can I do this via ansible? I want it to ask for the user@serverB password interactively while executing the playbook. Storing the password in ansible vault is also an option. Then I still do not know how to avoid the interactive password call of `ssh-copy-id` though.

I also added `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to the call because this is another interaction that normally requires user interaction when calling ssh-copy-id.

Answer (score 14):

If using the `ssh-copy-id` command is not a restriction, you might as well try out the Ansible [`authorized_key`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/authorized_key_module.html) module.

Then your code could look something like this:

```
authorized_key:
  user: <user>
  key: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/' + lookup('env', 'USER') + '/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try `sshpass` tool. It would require modification of your command like this:

```
command: sshpass -p password ssh-copy-id -i /home/{{user}}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@serverB
```

but there are other options how to provide the password -- see the `sshpass(1)` manual page.

Comment: That's a great approach. How can I interactively ask for the password before, so I can pass the variable to sshpass?

Comment: before what? You are running in cron.

Comment: this does not work on cento7 & above.

Comment: @akshaypmurgod why? What does it do?

Comment: It doesn`t error out. At the same time, ssh keys are not copied to the destination server. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @akshaypmurgod you can run the `ansible` or `ssh` in verbose mode to see what is going on there.